# Bootstrap postion Button Right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

this is my source code:

```
<p class="h1 p-3 mb-2 bg-danger text-white text-danger">Lagerbestand unter Mindestmenge! </p>
<br />

<div class="border  text-center">
<p class="h5 text-center">Durch Ihre Entnahme fällt der Lagerbestand unter die vom Administrator festgelegte Mindestmenge! </p>
<br>
<p class="h5">Sie sind dazu angehalten das Order-Managment zu Informieren! Mach Sie das indem Sie auf den Nachfolgenden Button drücken </p>
</div>

<br />
<button class="btn btn-warning btn-lg" onclick="sendMail()">Informieren</button>
<a asp-controller="Inventar" asp-action="EntnahmeSuccess" id="weiter" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Weiter</a>
```

and here is a photo where i want my button. I am literally not able to place it there :( Can you help?[image]

Comment: you can use this class "float-right" but I do recommend using  flex display on a parent div

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Bootstrap's Flex](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/) classes with space-between:

- `d-flex` --> `display: flex`
- `justify-content-between` --> `justify-content: space-between`

```html
<div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
  <button class="btn btn-warning btn-lg" onclick="sendMail()">Informieren</button>
  <a asp-controller="Inventar" asp-action="EntnahmeSuccess" id="weiter" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Weiter</a>
</div>
```

---

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<p class="h1 p-3 mb-2 bg-danger text-white text-danger">Lagerbestand unter Mindestmenge! </p>
<br />

<div class="border  text-center">
<p class="h5 text-center">Durch Ihre Entnahme fällt der Lagerbestand unter die vom Administrator festgelegte Mindestmenge! </p>
<br>
<p class="h5">Sie sind dazu angehalten das Order-Managment zu Informieren! Mach Sie das indem Sie auf den Nachfolgenden Button drücken </p>
</div>

<br />

<div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
  <button class="btn btn-warning btn-lg" onclick="sendMail()">Informieren</button>
  <a asp-controller="Inventar" asp-action="EntnahmeSuccess" id="weiter" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Weiter</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use bootstrap classes `d-flex justify-content-between` to apply the styles `display: flex; justify-content: space-between;`

```html
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.0/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<p class="h1 p-3 mb-2 bg-danger text-white text-danger">
  Lagerbestand unter Mindestmenge!
</p>
<br />

<div class="border text-center">
  <p class="h5 text-center">
    Durch Ihre Entnahme fällt der Lagerbestand unter die vom Administrator
    festgelegte Mindestmenge!
  </p>
  <br />
  <p class="h5">
    Sie sind dazu angehalten das Order-Managment zu Informieren! Mach Sie
    das indem Sie auf den Nachfolgenden Button drücken
  </p>
</div>

<br />
<div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
  <button class="btn btn-warning btn-lg" onclick="sendMail()">
    Informieren
  </button>
  <a
    asp-controller="Inventar"
    asp-action="EntnahmeSuccess"
    id="weiter"
    class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"
    >Weiter</a
  >
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: flex` for your container with (you can use `%` or `em`)

and set `justify-content: space-between;`

```html
<div style="display:flex; width: 20em; justify-content: space-between;">
<button>Informieren</button>
<button>Weiter</button>
</div>
```